# MVC, Razor - Submitting form (inside @if) gives empty object in post

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, http-post

I am trying to save some changes to a database.
The view gets a Model, and should be able to make changes and have them saved. However, when i submit the form, the ContactInfo parameter in the post method is not null, but all the properties are.

I'm using MVC5 with Razor. the script is in a seperate .ts-file

In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool SaveInfoChanges(ContactInfo editedContactInfo)
{
    // Save data
    return true;
}
```

Script:

```
export function saveInfoChanges() {
    $("#EditContactInfoForm").submit();
};
```

HTML:

```
@if (true)
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveInfoChanges", "ContactInfoBox", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EditContactInfoForm" }))
    }
        <table>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address1)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address2)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ZipAndCity)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Country)

            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address3, new { id = "ContactTypeInput", placeholder = "", style = "width:300px" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class ContactInfo
{
    public string ContactInfoBoxHeaderText { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string ZipAndCity { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

I can't think of more relevant information to give, but please don't hesitate to ask.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post the model class too?

Comment: Model class added.

Comment: The code you have shown works fine. If its not working, its due to code you have not shown us. (and the fact your method returns a `bool` instead of `ActionResult` suggests something strange)

Comment: Strange. The values just won't reach the controller. It should work, but it does not! Is the anything that I did not provide that could affect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the @if solved the problem. I just need to find another way to hide/show the elements.